# Automatically save login details in Chrome without a prompt

Tags: google-chrome

Although there is an experimental feature as : **chrome://flags/#enable-automatic-password-saving**


But enabling it hasn't changed anything at all. It still prompts to save password and doesn't when you click "nope".

Is that flag not compatible with Version 37.0.2062.124. If it is then any update on fix? or any other alternative ( like extensions )

NOTE: I have checked this issue page https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=367690